# Disable part of endpoints wordpress api

Tags: rest-api

I try to disable some parts of the API :

- display list of users
- display detail of users

But i want to keep the api to create and update users.

I did this :

```
add_filter( 'rest_endpoints', 'disable_custom_rest_endpoints' );
function disable_custom_rest_endpoints( $endpoints ) {
    
    
    if ( isset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/users'] ) ) {
        unset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/users'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/users/(?P<id>[\d]+)'] ) ) {
        unset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/users/(?P<id>[\d]+)'] );
    }

    return $endpoints;
}
```

My problem : this delete the possibility to update or create user as well

Is there another way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routes in question have two or three default endpoints:

- [`/wp/v2/users`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#list-users) — it has two endpoints, one GET and one POST, i.e. "List Users" (`GET /wp/v2/users`), and "Create a User" (`POST /wp/v2/users`).
- [`/wp/v2/users/<id>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#retrieve-a-user) — it has three endpoints, one GET, one POST and one DELETE, i.e. "Retrieve a User" (`GET /wp/v2/users/<id>`), "Update a User" (`POST /wp/v2/users/<id>`), and "Delete a User" (`DELETE /wp/v2/users/<id>`).

So in your code, you can unset the array (which represents an endpoint with specific HTTP request methods) in a route, if the request method is GET.

### Working Example

```php
function disable_custom_rest_endpoints( $endpoints ) {
    $routes = array( '/wp/v2/users', '/wp/v2/users/(?P<id>[\d]+)' );

    foreach ( $routes as $route ) {
        if ( empty( $endpoints[ $route ] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ( $endpoints[ $route ] as $i => $handlers ) {
            if ( is_array( $handlers ) && isset( $handlers['methods'] ) &&
                'GET' === $handlers['methods'] ) {
                unset( $endpoints[ $route ][ $i ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $endpoints;
}
```

Tried & tested working on WordPress 5.7.2 — only the `GET /wp/v2/users` and `GET /wp/v2/users/<id>` endpoints got removed/disabled.